# What do these jokes mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I confess! I found them really hard! I think the jokes are all about using witty words in English. [Here is the original source.](http://mashable.com/2014/06/23/intellectual-jokes/?utm_cid=mash-com-fb-main-link)

Please help me understand **them all**.

> (a) Your mother is so classless, she could be a Marxist utopia.
>
> (b) Why did the chicken cross the Mobius strip? To get the same side
>
> (c) Schrodinger's cat walks into a bar. And doesn't.
>
> (d) What's good anagram of Banach-Tarski? Banach-Tarski Banach-Tarski
>
> (e) What does a dyslexic, agnostic, insomniac spend most of his time doing? Styaing up all night wondering if there really is a dog *(I think I understand this. I'm a doctor!)*.
>
> (f) There are two types of people in this world. Those that can extrapolate to find missing information.
>
> (g) Yo momma's so fat, the probability of her being in an arbitrary point in a room is 1.
>
> (h) How many surrealists does it take to screw in a light bulb? A fish.
>
> (i) There's a band called 1023MB. They haven't had any gigs yet.

Comment: I'm tempted to close this, because it's really 9 questions rolled into 1. But I'll let the rest of the community (and rest of the mod team) have a look, and we'll see where this goes. In the meantime, thanks for the chuckles.

Comment: Most of these jokes require quite a lot of subject-specific knowledge. Only a very small number of people (mainly those with degrees in mathematics) would understand question d, and I think the only one I would expect most people to understand is h.

Comment: @sweeneyrod true but had they been in my mother tongue, I'd have understood them all far better.

Comment: I don't know about other languages, but for the most part, in English, if you have to explain the joke, it's not funny. [If you have a few spare hours, and you're a brave soul, read more.](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Dontexplainthejoke)

Comment: I wonder how can a joke has two meanings or can have several possible answers :) Joke is only joke if it has one way to convince the humor!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Firstly, thanks for introducing me to a few good jokes.

> (a) Your mother is so classless, she could be a Marxist utopia.

Two meanings of the word classless - "You mother is classless" = "Your mother behaves in an inappropriate way"; "A Marxist utopia is [classless](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_society))" = "A Marxist utopia doesn't have people divided into different classes".

> (b) Why did the chicken cross the Mobius strip? To get the same side

A [Möbius strip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_strip) is a plane (e.g. a piece of paper) with only one side. There is an old joke in English (that isn't ever really told straight, as everyone knows it) - "Why did the chicken cross the road? To get to the other side". The joke amusingly combines the form of the old joke with new content.

> (c) Schrödinger's cat walks into a bar. And doesn't.

[Schrödinger's cat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger%27s_cat) is a thought experiment in physics posulating a cat that is both dead and alive. There is a series of old jokes starting with "A man walks into a bar". The joke combines the two.

> (d) What's good anagram of Banach-Tarski? Banach-Tarski Banach-Tarski

The [Banach-Tarski theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_Tarski) in mathematics states that one can create two spheres out of one. The joke creates two "Banach-Tarski"s out of one.

> (e) What does a dyslexic, agnostic, insomniac spend most of his time doing? Staying up all night wondering if there really is a dog

An agnostic wonders if there is a God.
An insomniac stays up all night.
A dyslexic misspells words, so wonders about whether there is a Dog, rather than a God.

> (f) There are two types of people in this world. Those that can extrapolate to find missing information.

(and those that can't)
The listener is supposed to extrapolate to find missing information - the punchline of the joke.

> (g) Yo momma's so fat, the probability of her being in an arbitrary point in a room is 1.

"Yo momma's so fat" is the start of a series of "humourous" insults. The joke subverts the listener's expectations by providing an intellectual punchline that suggests she is everywhere in a room, rather than a traditional insult. The reference to probability is a reference to quantum mechanics, similar to joke c.

> (h) How many surrealists does it take to screw in a light bulb? A fish.

[Surrealists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrealism) are known for making art that contains strange things. This joke takes the form "How many people of a certain type does it take to screw in a light bulb?" and provides a suitably surreal(ist) punchline.

> (i) There's a band called 1023MB. They haven't had any gigs yet.

1024 MB (megabytes) = 1 GB (gigabyte). A gigabyte is often called a gig, which is also a word for a band's performance. The joke exploits this double meaning for humourous affect.

---

There are two parts to understanding these jokes. The first is to recognize that some of them are based on standard forms for jokes - "Your mother/yo momma is so `insult`, that `elaboration of insult`", "Why did the `something` cross the `something`?", "A `something` walks into a bar", "How many `people of a certain profession` does it take to change a lightbulb?".

For instance, joke h could have equally been one of the following:

"Yo momma is so surrealist, that fish diagonal exothermic."
"Why did the chicken go to the surrealist art gallery? It wanted to be enveloped by the melancholy fish of darkness."
"A surrealist walks into a bar... of pressurized fish and delicious ideologies."

The second part to understanding the jokes is to understand the (sometimes fairly esoteric) references they make - to politics, physics and art, for instance. This would be the much harder part for the average English speaker.

P.S. The other jokes on that page are also good.

Comment: I think you should clarify your definition of dyslexic; as it stands, it's incorrect and could even be taken with offense.

Comment: No taken offense.

Comment: May want to update the explanation for (g) to mention that this is related to quantum mechanics and thus is similar to (c).

Comment: @Schism I was trying to limit the definition of dyslexia to the aspect relevant to the joke - misspelling. I recognise that firstly, dyslexics don't misspell everything constantly, and secondly, that there are other aspects of dyslexia.

Comment: (g) is actually not about quantum mechanics. Probability is a strictly mathematical concept.

Comment: @Schism If what sweeneyrod says is true, then the only people offended wouldn't be able to read it anyway, so no harm done. If what he says is not true, then no one is really going to be offended by it anyway.

Comment: @kinokijuf I realize that, but talking about the probability of an object being in a given spot is a common physical interpretation of yo' mamas wavefunction ;)

Answer (score 8):

It is more about general knowledge than English-specific.

(a) [Marx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_in_Marxist_theory) wanted a society without classes. Utopia is an (unreachable) ideal place to live.

(b) This is not about English, but about the [Möbius strip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_strip). It’s a pun that merges math with that tritest of English riddles: “Why did the chicken cross the road?” (Answer: To get to the other side.)

(c) [Schrödinger’s cat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger%27s_cat) is a thought experiment, where a cat in a box is both alive or dead.

(d) Maths. The [Banach-Tarski](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Tarski_paradox) paradox states something like that you can decompose a ball into an infinite number of small points, then recreate from these small points two balls that have exactly the same shape as the first ball had.

(e) Dyslexic: god <> dog. Agnostic: “Is there a god?” Insomniac: Can’t sleep.

(f) Actually, there are only 10 types of people in the world. Those that understand binary counting, and those who don’t. ;)

(g) Probability and statistics. It just means she is everywhere in the room.

(h) What do surrealists do? Right. Illogical and abstract stuff.

(i) 1 Gigabyte = 1024 MB. 1 gigabyte is also called a gig. A gig is also a performance of a band.

Comment: Aside: the Banach-Tarski paradox actually only requires decomposing the ball into five pieces. The catch is that four of the pieces are so strangely shaped that it doesn't even make sense to ask about their volume.